# How to send query parameters through URL in JSP ( HTTP Status 500:Internal Server Error)

Tags: jsp, servlets, urlencode, url-encoding

I am trying to send query parameters through this URL from my JSP page to servlet page

```
<form method="get" action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/downloadFileServlet?id="<%=rs.getInt("id") %> >
```

The code in Servlet page to receive those parameters is

```
int uploadId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
```

But I am unable to because the URL as I check in chrome showed

```
http://localhost:8080/MajorProject/downloadFileServlet?
```

and what I intend it to show is

```
http://localhost:8080/MajorProject/downloadFileServlet?id=(whatever the id value is)
```

Let me know if you need the source code and stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the specifications ([RFC1866](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1866.txt), page 46; [HTML 4.x](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.3.4) section 17.13.3) state:

> If the method is "get" and the action is an HTTP URI, the user agent takes the value of action, **appends a `?' to it, then appends the form data set**, encoded using the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" content type.

So in your situtation you're "violating" specification by specifying url parameter by yourself.

---

In order to achieve what you want you can use hidden input fields like this:

```
<form action="${context}/downloadFileServlet" method="GET">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%= rs.getInt("id") %>" /> 
  <input type="submit" /> 
</form>
```